# Extracting ID into Sharepoint Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I want to create a calculated column, TaskId, that has the value of the [ID] field

[ID] cannot be directly used as it is not available at the time that the row is created.

The code I am attempting to use is

```
=" <img src=""http://Oursite/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
 & "    var clientContext=new SP.ClientContext.get_current();"
 & "    var list=clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());"
 & "    var TR=TR||this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;"
 & "    var item=list.getItemById( TR.id.split(String.fromCharCode(44))[1] );"
 & "    item.set_item("&CHAR(39)
 &                     "TaskId"
 &                      CHAR(39)&", Id);"
 & "    clientContext.load(item);"
 & "    item.update();"
 & "    }"">"
```

But the column value is still blank.

What have I done wrong?

**Update 2:**

What I've thought is that if I can automatically update another column on item creation, then hopefully the [Id] value sill be updated as a sideeffect.

Here's the code

```
=" <img  ""http://Oursite/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
&"var clientContext=new SP.ClientContext.get_current();"
& "var list=clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById       (SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());"
& "var CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();"
& "var query.ViewXml = @""<View>"
& " <Query>"
& "        <Where>"
&  "       <Eq>"
& "         <FieldRef Name='StaticItem/>"
& "         <Value Type='Text'>NotChecked</Value>"
& "        </Eq>"
& "        </Where>"
& "   </Query>"
& "    </View>"";"
& "var ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);"
& "clientcontext.Load(listItems);"
& "clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();"
& "var ListItem item = listItems[listItems.Count - 1];"
& "var item[""StaticItem""] = ""Checked"";"
& "item.Update();"
& "clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();"
& "    }"">"
```

But this is not doing anything correctly either. What is appearing in the column value is

NotChecked    ";var ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems      (query);clientcontext.Load(listItems);clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();var ListItem item = listItems[listItems.Count - 1];var item["StaticItem"] = "Checked";item.Update();clientcontext.ExecuteQuery(); }">

Thanks for all your help (don't all respond at once :) )

**Update 3**

Another code nippert I've been working with, doesn't work either. The column value remains blank.

```
 =" <img  ""http://Oursite/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
&"var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();"
&"var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);"
&"var i;"
&"var thisID;"
&"var count=CountDictionary(items);"
&"for (i=0,i<count;i++)"
&"{"
&"  thisID=items[i].id;"
&"}"
& "    }"">"
```

**Update 4**

No luck with this one either. The field StaticItem remains blank.

Any assistance anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
="<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
&"var clientContext=new SP.ClientContext.get_current();"
 & "var list=clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById    (SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());"
 & "var TR=this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;"
 & "var item=list.getItemById( TR.id.split(String.fromCharCode(44))[1] );"
& "item.set_item('StaticItem', ""Checked"");"
& "item.update();"
&"clientcontext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);"
& "    }"">"
```

Comment: As you already said that the `ID` column is not available until the item is created you can probably try to use a workflow to run twice. Some examples over [**here**](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/22977/20540) and [**here**](http://www.spankh.com/archives/121).

Comment: Workflows are unavailable. The only available method I have to use is by calculated columns.